# Learn Python the Hard Way- Exercise 13 "need more than 1 value to unpack"

Tags: python

This is my first question and I'm very new at programming, please be patient. :) Thanks for your help!

(PS, I reposted to fix the formatting)

I've looked through several related questions but still don't get it. Basically I need to know: why am I getting the error "need more than 1 value to unpack"?

Another thread directed me to check my path environment variable, which I think is ok.

Here it is:

```
PS C:\Users\monic> python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sys import argv
>>> script, first, second, third = argv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: you try unpacking `argv` variable into 4 variables , how ever `argv` just have 3 potential variable in it, (maybe you pass one variable less)